# How to Customise setSubject of Dompdf? How get specifc subject and pdf name choosing ID's

Tags: php

Guys I have this PHP code which is normally provided by DOMPDF

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('How To Create and Send An HTML Email w/ a PDF Attachment')
            ->setTo(array($post->email => $post->name)) // Array of people to send to
    ->setFrom(array('no-reply@net.meetme.com' => 'Nirmohi+')) // From:
    ->setBody($html_message, 'text/html')
            ->attach(Swift_Attachment::newInstance($pdf_content, 'nettuts.pdf', 'application/pdf'));
```

And I want Change Subject Name and PDF name dynamically ... like..

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('A New Mail Received Frome "NAMEID"')
            ->setTo(array('MYEMAIL@gmail.com' => $post->name))
    ->setFrom(array('no-reply@net.meetme.com' => $post->name))
    ->setBody($html_message, 'text/html')
            ->attach(Swift_Attachment::newInstance($pdf_content, 'SMILE.pdf', 'application/pdf'));
```

---

I want to get data from my HTML form.
eg.

```
<input id="NAMEID">
<input id="SMILE">
```

I am new in PHP ... Pls Help me Asap..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//if your html form is posted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//you probably want to check for faulty values here (e.g. virus.pdf etc)

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('A New Mail Received Frome'.$_POST['nameid'])
    ->setTo(array($post->email => $post->name)) // Array of people to send to
    ->setFrom(array('no-reply@net.meetme.com' => 'Nirmohi+')) // From:
    ->setBody($html_message, 'text/html')
    ->attach(Swift_Attachment::newInstance($pdf_content, $_POST['smile'], 'application/pdf'));

}

?>

<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="tmp.php">
    <input type="text" name="nameid" />
    <input type="text" name="smile" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```